# Understanding Bash List syntax definition

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

Man bash states that a `List` is

> a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `;`, `&`, `&&`, or `||`, and optionally terminated
>          by one of `;`, `&`, or `<newline>`.
>
> Of these list operators, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, followed by `;` and `&`, which have equal precedence.
>
> A sequence of one or more newlines may appear in a list instead of a semicolon to delimit commands.

So basically any of the listed control operators may separate pipelines, of which a List consists. Also `;`, `&` may as well as separate pipelines inside a list, they also may terminate the whole List.

From what I understand this bash script falls into the definition of a List:

```
pipeline1 && pipeline2; pipeline3
```

am I correct? I have one `&&` and one `;` which separate my three pipelines.

**If yes, why is it a List and not two Lists?**

What I do not grasp is why it is said that `;`, `&` are valid for separating pipelines as well as terminating them?

In my example does `;` separates List pipelines or terminates the first and starts the second one?

Comment: `bash` doesn't really care about the distinction between a list with three pipelines and a list consisting of a (sub)list (itself consisting of two pipelines) and a pipeline.

Comment: yea I know it. I am wondering about a syntactical point of view.

Comment: @oguzismail The definition of `list` is used in the definition of nearly every compound statement.

Comment: @chepner I think it just convolutes the documentation

Comment: Bash grammar is complex; there's really isn't a simple way to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a statement like:

```
if pipeline1 && pipeline2; pipeline3; then echo "foo"; fi
```

The first `;` separates the pipelines in the list, the second one terminates the list.

This is one list because the syntax of `if` is:

> if `list`; then `list`; [ elif `list`; then `list`; ] ... [ else `list`; ] fi

Comment: good point. So, in other words, we should call it one List taking as long as we can before the first, say, newline character.

Comment: It's more complicated than that, because you can have nested lists, e.g. an `if` statement inside the condition or body of another `if`.

Comment: but `if` statement is a `Compound Command` as far as I understand it and won't create nested lists.

Comment: I guess it's safe to say that whether `command && command; command && command` is two lists or one list is undefined.

Comment: You can definitely nest them, e.g. `if foo; then if x; then echo foo-x; else echo foo-y; fi;`

Comment: It's like asking whether `a + b + c` is one expression or two expressions. You can view it either way, the result is the same.